# Multi Provider with Stream

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to have two stream providers of type QuerySnapshot from two different Firebase collections. but i am lost. here is my code

[here is the dart file...](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UE1S7X9w-I8ZBXSun2O7n7XASr0gtHZW/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: It must be a type of ```QuerySnapshot<Map>```

Comment: No... as far i am going use in another page

Comment: @HadiNorouzi i am just confused on how to use stream with multi provider

Comment: StreamProvider is from provider package or extend ChangeNotifier?

Comment: @HadiNorouzi yes can you show me a sample code on how to use it multi provider

Comment: You can use ```StreamBuilder``` inside ```StreamBuilder``` , or if you want to use RxDart, search for ```Observable.combineLatest2```

Comment: i have use streambuilder inside streambuilder but i am getting error before the values comes up..... it will first show null error after it will show the data. @ikerfah

Comment: Yes obvious, ```StreamBuilder``` is asynchronous, you need to check the status before rendering the UI, you have to check for ```snapshot.hasError``` , and in the ```else ```  you can check for ```snapshot.connectionState```, if ```none``` you have your data, if ```waiting``` show a loader

Comment: okay... the i will check the snapshot.hasError... thanks...

Comment: @ikerfah still the same

Comment: Update your code please

Comment: @ikerfah i have share the dart file....

Comment: it is showing an empty container? not null?

Comment: ok... after i run it on real device... all is fine...